# SAP NetWeaver 7 trial and SAP .NET connector 3.0 - available functions?

Tags: asp.net, connection, sap-dotnet-connector, netweaver

I am using the SAP .NET Connector 3.0 to connect to some NetWeaver instance running on another machine. It all works nice, but the tutorial only connects to one function called **STFC_CONNECTION**. To do this, I am using this code:

```
function = destination.Repository.CreateFunction("STFC_CONNECTION");
```

Problem is, how do I know what other functions I can call? I there an overview of the available functions and return values? I have a login for the SAP site, so that's not a problem.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know ***all*** function that can be called, you can check the table TFDIR with parameter FMODE ='R' (for Remote) using transaction se16. However, this will clearly be far too much info, since there is no explanation of what the functions do, or how they relat to each others.

another possibility is to use the BAPI transaction to get info on disponible operation by functionnal area.

Last, if you know some functions that interest you, you can search for function with the same prefix, or inportant part (ie *INFTY* for HR for exemple) using transaction se37. Please note that in this case, returned function can be inaccessible by RFC : you will have to check in the function's properties if the execution type is 'Remote'.

Regards
Guillaume

Answer (score 2):

You'll need access to the SAP system using the SAP GUI, otherwise you won't be able to read the documentation. Use the transaction SE80 / Repository Explorer to search for function modules. Clicking on the + button will extend the selection screen. In the additional selection options, make sure to select only RFC-enabled function modules.

EDIT: Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710705/how-to-search-for-available-functions-and-tables-on-a-sap-system)...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out ... just type *SE37* as transaction and use a filter in the search box like *STFC_** and it will find all the functions including the parameters and return values.

Comment: You still have to make sure that the function is Remote-enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The description at [Consuming SAP XI Web Service with Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/403b0381-b17b-2d10-e1b1-9741b4ad4897?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true) provides a sample worked example for Visual Studio 2008.

SAP support either the RFC stack (SOAP, WSDL, UDDI) or the direct .NET Connector.

Comment: Thats not what I am looking for ... I want an overview of the functions that are available for calling. I am using RFC to call...

Answer (score 0):

There is also the bapi explorer transaction "BAPI" who will show you the BAPI functions divided into functional areas.