# What data is available through SAP JCo

Tags: sap-basis, bapi, jco

SAP JCo provides SAP system, process and OS related data.

Is there any document or any place where all the data is enlisted, and what BAPI tables are required to access this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JCo is used to call some functions in SAP. Those functions must be prepared for this kind of call (remote enabled).

You can get an idea of the functions available via the answers to the following questions :

- [how to search for available functions on sap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710705/how-to-search-for-available-functions-and-tables-on-a-sap-system)
- [sap and jco3 : print a list of BAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463182/sap-and-sapjco3-print-a-list-of-bapis-in-my-java-program)

Answer (score 1):

You don't access data directly through JCo, you usually call remote-enabled function modules to get your data from the system. There are also function modules that can read table data and return the column values.

There is no complete list of all available function modules. The available function modules depend on the system you're running (4.6, 4.7, mySAP ERP 2005, ECC 6.0 with or without Enhancement Packages). For an (incomplete) overview have a look at the BAPI transaction.